# Which thread receives SIGURG?

Tags: networking, tcp, signals, socket, multithreading

I recently wrote a "study note" about Unix, and I made following proposition about multi-threaded processes:

> it will be almost impossible for the kernel to identify the thread that should receive SIGURG, when a TCP packet with "urgent" bit is received

in the 3rd paragraph of [section 1.1](https://dannyniu.github.io/Ouch/versions/2021-01-23/ch01-limit-api-use.html#h2-1-1-ed8d4), and I'd like to fact check this.

The standard made no provision on this, and left the entire TCP `URG` flag, `MSG_OOB`, and `SIGURG` implementation and protocol -specific.

But what about existing practice? Would the operating system kernel send `SIGURG` to the threads blocked in a `recv(2)` call on the socket that received the TCP `URG` flag? Are there implementations capable of specifying a thread as the owner of a socket? Would there be other behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 3 implementations I surveyed, Darwin, FreeBSD, and Linux, the main thread receives the signal. And if the main thread blocks it with a mask, no thread receives the signal.